# Convert date time format

Tags: javascript

I want to convert my date to this YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS format. So I tired to use below code,

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 05, 12, 07, 0, 0));
document.write(date.toISOString());
```

But output of this code is

```
2016-06-12T07:00:00.000Z
```

Again I removed after last dot index values, finally I got expected output. Is it possible to covert directly with out removing any values?

Comment: [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: use `(new Date(2016,5,9,7)).toISOString().replace(/\..+/,'')` or parse each part of the date struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What **Jonathan Lonowski** mentioned is perfectly fine but you should be using any library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

```
//var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 05, 12, 07, 0, 0));
var date = moment("2016-05-12 07:00:00");
console.log(date.format("YYYY-MM-dd[T]HH:mm:SS"));
```

Or if you are using jQuery, then you can [jQuery Date Format](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat)

```
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 05, 12, 07, 0, 0));
console.log($.format.date(date, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:SS"));
```